# Multiple Rails Helpers w/ Same Method Name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two different helper files (photos_helper & comments_helper) w/ that have a method named `actions_for`. How can I explicitly call which helper method that I need? I know that I could just rename one of them but I would prefer to keep them the same. I tried `PhotosHelper::actions_for` but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Rails 3 all helpers are always (in Rails 3.1 a patch exists to selectively allow helpers again) included. What's happening behind the scenes:

```
class YourView
  include ApplicationHelper
  include UserHelper
  include ProjectHelper

  ...
end
```

So depending on the order Rails includes them, any of your `actions_for` methods will be used. There is no way you can explicitly chose one of them.

If you would have to explicitly call `ProjectHelper.action_for`, you could also name your methods `project_action_for` - simplest solution.

Answer (score 6):

Make both of them a `Class Method`

```
module LoginsHelper
  def self.your_method_name
    "LoginsHelper"
  end
end
```

AND

```
module UsersHelper
  def self.your_method_name
    "UsersHelper"
  end
end
```

Then in View

```
   LoginsHelper.your_method_name #Gives 'LoginsHelper'
```

AND

```
   UsersHelper.your_method_name #Gives 'UsersHelper'
```

Comment: However this doesn't allow access to any other "regular" ActionView::Helper methods like link_to, _url, image_tag within there.